# Java http client to read response greater than 16384 characters

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, rest-assured

I'm trying to read http response in java by posting a http call to a server (old struts based app) which returns HTML. I've tried using http client in rest-assured framework and using apache http client. Both are returning response string truncated to 16384 characters.

Relevant code tried with apache client:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httppost, httpContext);
String responseHtml = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
responseHtml.length() // returns 16384 where as response should contain more data as per trying same call manually in browser
```

I've tried few other libraries & ways to convert input stream to string. They also return only 16384 characters

```
// Approach using apache IOUtils
String responseHtml = IOUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());

// Approach using guava CharStreams
String responseHtml = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), Charsets.UTF_8));

// Approach using java.util.scanner
Scanner s = new Scanner(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()).useDelimiter("\\A");
String responseHtml = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
```

Is there a way in java to read a http response larger than 16384 characters?

Comment: Seems more like the response actually doesn't contain more characters. Maybe differences in the request between java and browser? A bug in your server? [Partial request/response](https://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/)?

Comment: Agreed. You are using the client right. And I've never come across a size limitation. Why don't you point it at some large public url and see what happens.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Thanks for the suggestion. I tried get request for one of the biggest wikipedia article. It is able to return more than 16384 characters. Gist -> https://gist.github.com/endeepak/19a0a543f71d64405992f48a74ce3cba. So it could be problem with the server. It is a struts application hosted in tomcat and served behind ngnix proxy. I wonder how it works properly in browser.

Comment: @zapl, Thanks for referring the article. The response status code received in my test is '200 OK' but content is truncated.

Comment: The problem seems to because of chunked response from server. I noticed header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" in response. Apache http client is supposed to handle chunked response without extra code, but it isn't. Now I just have get that fixed.